# How to access a rejected object containing an error inside next .then()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a chain of promises where in a certain promise I want it to log the error but pass the rest of the data to the next `.then()`

```
    const parseQuery = (movies) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const queries = Object.keys(req.query).length;
      if(debug) console.log('Parsing ', queries ,'queries');
      if(queries > 0) { //If there's any query run this
        //When calling two parameters
        if(req.query.index && req.query.trailer) reject(errorify('You can\'t call two parameters at once.'));
        //When calling index
        else if(req.query.index){
          var index = Number(req.query.index);
          if(debug) console.log('Calling index ',index);
          if(index<movies.length && index>=0){ //Index is a number and in range
            movie = movies[index];
            movie.index = index;
          }
          else if(isNaN(index) || index <= 0 || index>movies.length) {
            let index = random.exclude(0,movies.length-1);
            movie = movies[index];
            reject({
              msg: errorify('Index is not a number or it\'s out of range.'),
              movie //Add the var as a property
             });
          }
          if(debug) console.log('Requested: ', movie.title);
          }
        //When calling trailer
        else if(req.query.trailer){
          movie = {title: req.query.trailer};
        }
        resolve([movie]); //Pass the result as a one item array
      }
      else {
        resolve(movies); //If no query is called just pass the movies through
      }
     });
  };

  readDB(file)
    .then(parseQuery)
      .then(
        result => { selectMovie(result); },
        reason => { console.log(reason.err); selectMovie(reason.movie); 
});
```

For some reason, `result` works fine but reason gives me undefined when I try to access the object properties (`reason.err`, `reason.movie`) but it gives me this when I call the object reason:

```
    Error:  { msg: 
   Error: Index is not a number or it's out of range. Selecting a random movie.
       at errorify (/Users/gonzo/Projects/JS/random-movie-trailer/src/controllers/routes.js:16:10)
       at Promise (/Users/gonzo/Projects/JS/random-movie-trailer/src/controllers/routes.js:61:20)
       at Promise (<anonymous>)
       at parseQuery (/Users/gonzo/Projects/JS/random-movie-trailer/src/controllers/routes.js:43:12)
       at <anonymous>
       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:169:7),
  movie: { title: 'The Hero', usersScore: '77%', criticsScore: '64%' } }
```

So from what I can see `reason` is an Error object with a `msg` property which is also an Error.

Then my question. If rejecting an obj to pass both the error and the movie is no solution how could I pass both values to the next Promise? So that I can use `reason.err` and `reason.movie`

Comment: Please show us the whole code that creates the reason object. The supposed result of `console.log(reason)` doesn't match the `reject({err: new Error('Error'), movie})` line at all.

Comment: How are `resolve()` and `reject()` related to `.then()` chained to `readDB(file)`? What do you mean by "`//Previous reject and result`"?

Comment: Assuming it is `parseQuery()` that creates this rejected promise, that is the code that can put whatever it wants to into the reject `reason`.  I'd also suggest that if this isn't really a "failure", but just a different return condition, you may want to change that the resolved value is so that you can just process both types of returns there and save the rejected state for an actual failure.

Comment: I wrote it  poorly. Sorry: //Previous reject and result are the reason and results creators. I’ll update my code

Answer (score 0):

In the end I opted to avoid throwing an error and went with what @jfriend00 told me: I now send the object appending only a `msg` if there was an 'error' and in the function that handles the ouput I put an if statement checking if the object has a `msg` property. Like so:

```
if(movies.msg) {
   console.log('Index :',movies.index);
   console.error(movies.msg);
   movies = [movies.movie];
}

selectRandom(movies)
  .then(requestTrailer)
```